# Indexing of python 2D list

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing

In order to access the second dimension of a 2D numpy array, we could use e.g.

```
A[:,0:9]
```

How could we do this to a 2D list?

Comment: Python lists do not really have dimensions like `numpy` arrays do. There really are no "2D lists." You have to write the logic yourself, although, it should be relatively straightforward using a combination of slicing and list-comprehensions.

Comment: Stick to the arrays. Despite their superficial similarities, lists and arrays work very differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array and nested list version:

```
In [163]: A=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [164]: Al = A.tolist()
```

For sliced indexing, a list comprehension (or mapping equivalent) works fine:

```
In [165]: A[:,1:3]
Out[165]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
In [166]: [l[1:3] for l in Al]
Out[166]: [[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10]]
```

For advanced indexing, the list requires a further level of iteration:

```
In [167]: A[:,[0,2,3]]
Out[167]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  6,  7],
       [ 8, 10, 11]])

In [169]: [[l[i] for i in [0,2,3]] for l in Al]
Out[169]: [[0, 2, 3], [4, 6, 7], [8, 10, 11]]
```

Again there are various mapping alternatives.

```
In [171]: [operator.itemgetter(0,2,3)(l) for l in Al]
Out[171]: [(0, 2, 3), (4, 6, 7), (8, 10, 11)]
```

`itemgetter` uses `tuple(obj[i] for i in items)` to generate those tuples.

Curiously, `itemgetter` returns tuples for the list index, and lists for slices:

```
In [176]: [operator.itemgetter(slice(1,3))(l) for l in Al]
Out[176]: [[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasteful but should work:

```
list(zip(*(list(zip(*A))[0:9])))
```

Slightly more economical using `itertools.isclice`:

```
list(zip(*(itertools.islice(zip(*A), 0, 9))))
```

Or one could use `map` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
list(map(operator.itemgetter(slice(0,9)), A))
```

Comment: It seems over-engineered to me. Just a simple `[sub[0:9] for sub in A]` works nicely: it is efficient and readable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga fair enough.

Comment: In the end, I'm not sure efficiency matters here... if OP want's efficient multidimensional slicing, they should use numpy!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wouldn't at all be surprised if your solution is faster.

Comment: Slices work with lists ok, it's list indexing that needs extra help, such as the `itemgetter`, which is just a class wrapper for a list comprehension.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, I don't follow. What is your point? I'm only using `itemgetter` in order to be able to apply `map`.

Comment: It's more of an observation about `itemgetter`.  It may be useful, but it doesn't add a compiled array-like access to lists.

Comment: @hpaulj Ok. Yeah, I think I'm just delaying the inevitable: Having to admit that the plain list comprehension is indeed the best solution here -- short of switching to `numpy` that is.